# How to subsitute contents of a file contained within the output of a variable

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I have searched for variable syntax and other commands but I cannot get through.

I have some folders created with btrfs snapshots.
Within each folder there is a file called `/etc/fstab` that I need to edit and replace always the same value with the one from the folder's path. For example I replace `@` with `@snapshots/daily/root2020-12-27_19H05`

The variable here is `2020-12-27_19H05` always prefixed with `root`.

Before I get to editing a file, 1st step is to do something simple like making a simple bash script which creates a file as root in each folder found by the variable, I have:

```
cd /.snapshots/daily
SNAPSHOTS=$(ls -d root*/)
echo > $SNAPSHOTS/test
```

But I get the following error:

```
bash: $SNAPSHOTS/test: ambiguous redirect
```

I tried various ways with "", '', (), {} in every location I could think of but it fails. I tried with SUDO in some places but fails as well. It seems common on internet but what I read didn't me understand and fix my issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Unix Stackexchange! Your description for the problem is very clear, but I find your title a bit hard to understand for the first reading. That doesn't encourage other users to click the title and see inside what your post actually says, and it's also bad for search engine optimization. Maybe you could reconsider the title phrasing?

Comment: You're right, I changed it, trying to keep it short but also meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SNAPSHOTS` variable contains spaces. To redirect to its value, double quote it:

```
echo > "$SNAPSHOTS"/test
```

This will most likely not do what you want as you seems to want to store multiple path in `SNAPSHOTS`. You can't store multiple separate strings in one string and think you can retrieve them back out of that single string correctly. It should really be an array and [you don't need `ls` at all here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985):

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

SNAPSHOTS=(root*/)

for snap in "${SNAPSHOTS[@]}"; do
    echo >"$snap"/test
done
```

or just

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

for snap in root*/; do 
    echo >"$snap"/test
done
```

Setting the `nullglob` shell option ensures that the pattern is removed completely if it doesn't match anything. Without `nullglob`, the pattern is retained as is if it doesn't match anything.

If it's not many thousands of files that you want to put an empty line into, you could also do

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

SNAPSHOTS=(root*/)
echo | tee "${SNAPSHOTS[@]/%//test}" >/dev/null
```

If you really just want to *create* the files (not write an empty line into them), then use `touch`:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

SNAPSHOTS=(root*/)
touch "${SNAPSHOTS[@]/%//test}" 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `SNAPSHOTS` contains more than one directory.

You can see the problem when you insert a line `set -x` before the `echo` command. This will show the expansion of `$SNAPSHOTS`.

Use a loop to call the `echo` command for every matching directory.

```
for i in root*/
do
    if [ "$i" != 'root*/' ]
    then
        touch "$i"/test
    fi
done
```

The additional `if` avoids running `touch 'root*/test'` in case there is no matching directory.

Answer (score 0):

You guys know everything and explain the answer so we can understand, this website is an incredible database.

In the end I went with

```
for i in root*/
do
    if [ "$i" != 'root*/' ]
    then
        sudo touch "$i"/test
    fi
done
```

Using sudo here cuz those snapshot folders are owned by root.

So now I understand my first step which is to create, rename, delete, change permissions, etc. on a file within a list of folders returned inside a variable.

I am now bringing this a step deeper, which is to edit a file within each of the folders returned by the variable, and replace a fixed value by a variable one which equals the value returned by the variable at the start.

I can't understand how to integrate a variable in the value I want to replace.

I changed my snapshots structure to make the script easier (for me). So now the variable listing all folders within a folder returns the following:

```
echo $SNAPSHOTS
2020-12-22_19H05/
2020-12-23_19H05/
2020-12-24_19H05/
2020-12-25_19H05/
2020-12-26_19H05/
2020-12-27_19H05/
2020-12-28_19H05/
```

Within each of those folders, for which the directory names change every day (oldest day gets deleted and today gets added), there is a file located at /etc/fstab, so `2020-12-22_19H05/etc/fstab` as an example.

I need to edit that file, search for the fixed value "@home" and replace it with the variable value part of a fixed prefix string, like:

```
@snapshots/daily/home/$VARIABLE
```

The $VARIABLE = the directory names returned by the first variable listed above.

So within folder `2020-12-22_19H05/` the file `/etc/fstab` would be edited to replace `@home` by `@snapshots/daily/home/2020-12-22_19H05` without the `/` at the end, it needs to be omited/truncated.
And so on for all folders found by the first variable.

I am expecting sed and possibly % to be used, but I am really out of clue as to what to search on internet to 1-get an answer but mostly 2-understand the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I was able to edit each file within my variable with a FIXED value using "sudo sed s/"@home"/"@home2"/g $SNAPSHOTS". But I need to replace "@home2" by "$SNAPSHOTS" value.

Comment: I meant editing "@home" by "$SNAPSHOTS", not editing "@home2". I am passed the 5mins editing delay. :)